# How to pass and get URL parameters in IBM Webpshere Portal 6.1 JSF Portlets?

Tags: jsf, portlet, websphere-6.1, websphere-portal

I have a simple HTML page which contains a form (uses GET method), whose action is a portal page containing a JSF portlet. **I need to access the parameters passed in to the portal page in my portlet - how can I achieve this?**

I have tried to access the parameter `code` on the view page using following code but the value comes up as `null`.

```
java.util.Map requestMap = javax.faces.context.FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap(); 
String code = requestMap.get("code");
```

At some other forum it was suggested that I need to pass the the portlet id as request parameter in order to have the portlet access to passed request parameters. If that is true where/how can I lookup my portlet ID so that portlet has access to request parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look into whether the WebSphere implementation of [public render parameters](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpdoc/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.wp.ent.doc_v6101/dev/pltcom_pubrndrprm.html) supports this. If the `ExternalContext` request parameter map does not expose these values, you can cast [the request](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequest()) to a `PortletRequest` and make use of the `Map<String,String[]> getPublicParameterMap()` method.

Comment: At what place the casting shall be done? I believe it has to be done before the portlet's view page is rendered. As once the view page is rendered, the request parameters are already lost.

Answer (score 0):

See my article Passing query parameters to JSR-286 portlets  [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Passing_query_parameters_to_JSR-286_portlets_using_existing_IBM_WebSphere_Portal_capabilities).

I know this is a supported way to do it.  I have seen other articles that claim you can simply cast the PortletRequest to something and get the parameters.  This is probably not supported in that it depends on a particular implementation and reference to an internal class name.  I recommend the above.